# ¿ Que hace la funcion getView() de SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, xml, sap

Buenas tardes,
Estoy en pleno desarrollo de una aplicacion utilizando SAPUI5, Tengo serias dudas con este trozo de codigo y me gustaria entender que hace cada funcion, que se esta haciendo realmente.

esto sucede dentro del "Controller" de una "View" aqui dejo la view:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui el Controller:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que me gustaria entender es este trozo de codigo:

```
var ModelDriver = new JSONModel();
            this.getView().setModel(ModelDriver, "infodriver");
            ModelDriver = this.getView().getModel("infodriver");
            ModelDriver.setData({
                //DriverId: "",
                DriverImage: "http://www.buscandolalibertad.com/ext/rockettheme/rokbb/noavatar.jpg"
                //DriverName: "",
                //DriverLastName: ""
            });
```

Gracias de antemano. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Te lo explciare como yo lo entiendo el this.getView() se usa para acceder como a la vista de ese controlador que lo llama luego para acceder a uno de los controles de esa vista lo haces por byId(), de hecho a partir creo que de la version 1.30 o 1.44 lei que ya no es necesario el getView() sino que lo puedes hacer directamente asi var = this.byId('id_elemento')

tambien puedes acceder pero no lo he probado a un elemento de otra vista que no es la comun, usando sap.ui.getCore().byId(...)

En cuanto a la otra parte de tu pregunta lo que estas haciendo es creando un modelo y asignandoselo a un elemento para luego enviarle la data de ese modelo

Creas un modelo
var ModelDriver = new JSONModel();

A esa vista le asignas un modelo por decirlo asi, la otra parte no estoy muy seguro, el "infodriver" ya que yo lo hago un poco diferente pero es lo mismo
            this.getView().setModel(ModelDriver, "infodriver");

No entiendo mucho esta linea ya que estas obteniendo el modelo de la vista
            ModelDriver = this.getView().getModel("infodriver");

envias la data al modelo de manera que la puedas usar  el modelo con data en la vista en la parte de la imagen que le indicas {infodriver>/DriverImage}
            ModelDriver.setData({
                DriverImage: "http://www.buscandolalibertad.com/ext/rockettheme/rokbb/noavatar.jpg"

Bueno ya a estas alturas seguro sabras mas que yo que llevo apenas un mes por este mundo del ui5